# Is there webcam recording software that can add a background to your recording? Ubuntu 18

Tags: software-center, webcam

I did the search in Ubuntu for video recording software and there was loads of software available, but I couldn't find one that says it will add a background.  Skype recently came out with a feature where you can choose a background for your video call.  I don't seem to have that option, maybe it's because they haven't added it for Linux.  But that gave me the idea to look for some webcam recording software that has that feature so I can record a video without my messy room being the background.  Anyone know of such software?
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your release. The closest is Ubuntu Core 18 as specialist *snap* based releases use the *yy* format, unlike *yy.mm* used by server & desktops releases, but your question seems to be more a standard *yy.mm* release not a *yy* release.  *yy* releases are limited to using *snaps* unlike *yy.mm* releases which can use *debs*, *snaps* and more.

Comment: version 18.04.  All I have ever seen written is 18.04 so I just assumed the "18" would do it.